# refactoring of the java code

Tags: java, oop, refactoring, ooad

I have a code which was not refactored at all. I refactored it to some extent..but stuck at a point where I cannot think of anything further.

Tractor.java:

```
   package com.farm;

public class Tractor implements MethodsInterface{

private int[] position;

private int[] field;

private String orientation;

public Tractor(){
    position  = new int[]{0,0};
    field = new int[]{5,5};
    orientation = "N";
}

public void move(String command) {
if(command=="F"){
moveForwards();
}else if(command=="T"){
turnClockwise();
}

}

private void moveForwards() {
if(orientation=="N"){
position = new int[]{position[0], position[1]+1}; }else if(orientation == "E"){ position = new int[]{position[0]+1, position[1]}; }else if(orientation == "S"){ position = new int[]{position[0], position[1]-1}; }else if(orientation == "W"){ position = new int[]{position[0]-1, position[1]}; } if(position[0]>field[0]||position[1]>field[1]){

try {
    throw new TractorInDitchException();
} catch (TractorInDitchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}

private void turnClockwise() {
if(orientation=="N"){
orientation = "E";
}else if(orientation == "E"){
orientation = "S";
}else if(orientation == "S"){
orientation = "W";
}else if(orientation == "W"){
orientation = "N";
}
}


public int getPositionX() {
return position[0];
}

public int getPositionY() {
return position[1];
}

public String getOrientation() {
return orientation;
}
}
```

TractorInDitchException.java

```
package com.farm;

public class TractorInDitchException extends Exception{

}
```

MethodsInterface.java

```
package com.farm;

public interface MethodsInterface {

    public int getPositionX();
    public int getPositionY();
    public String getOrientation();
}
```

What else could be refactored...any suggestions please?

Comment: Unless you actually own `farm.com`, you should use a different package name.

Comment: @SLaks its all under same package... so thats why i used it.

Comment: This should be on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DaveNewton i didnt knew about this. I will post it there too

Comment: Seen my Direction class here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1240759/82118 for some ideas on other ways to handle the turns.

Comment: @user1147717: That doesn't make a difference.  You should only name packages after domain names that you own.  This prevents conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd override all the `Exception` constructors in your `TractorInDitchException`.

It's not used anywhere.  What will cause you to throw that exception?

You can turn clockwise or counterclockwise with finer control than compass points.  I'd rewrite that method to pass in a delta in heading angle.

Why the hard-wired position and field arrays?  Pass them into constructors.  Give some indication as to what they mean.

Not much of an abstraction here.  I could think of lots of other things to say about tractors:  velocity vectors, acceleration, weight, fuel consumption rate, towing capacity, etc.  This feels like an anemic domain model to me.  There's little or no imagination at work.

Comment: What do you mean by overiding Exception consturctors? and also what do you mean by finer control in the methods? Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: Exception has four constructors - override them in your class.  Look at the javadocs.  As for finer control, if I'm headed dead east and I turn 90 degrees clockwise, I'm facing north when I'm done.  Can't I turn 45 degrees for northeast heading?  How 'bout 10 degrees?  How 'bout 5?  How 'bout 1 degree?  That's what I mean by "finer control".  And isn't turning 90 degrees counterclockwise to head south a -90 degree turn?  It's a better abstraction if you express it as relative heading.  Vectors are so much easier here.

Comment: ok I have now overriden the four constructors.. but still the finer control point, i am confused as to how to implement it.

Comment: It's just a suggestion.  It's probably more than you're capable of.  Think about it and try to consider it in the future.  Go read about vectors.  Carry on!